# How to remove black space IOS Navigation-embedded View?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

A screen I'm segueing to has this black bar on the top of the screen
[Black Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3y6G.png)
I haven't done any code on this VC, and I couldn't figure out a way to remove this "bar."

On the storyboard, it looks normal but doesn't when I run the app
[Storyboard image (Working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCPj1.png)

Edit:

I have enabled `Presentation: Full Screen` but it still hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) First you have to tap on the "top bar" of your viewcontroller, click on the button to the left.  (With the blue background)

[image: first]

2.) Click on the 'Attribute Inspector' in the right-side panel

[image: two]

3.) Change presentation from "Automatic" to "Full Screen"

[image: third]

Comment: Hey, I have already done that but it still does that on the app once it's on the simulator

Comment: @AAdam Try to remove the segue and connect a new one. Use ”Show” :)

Comment: Yea it did! Thanks a lot